# Reporting non-significant regression analysis?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, anova, spss, regression-coefficients

[image]

As a result of attached regression analysis I found non-significant results and I was wondering how to interpret and report this. I am a self-learner and checked Google but unfortunately almost all of the examples are about significant regression results.

Hypothesis 7 predicted that receiving more likes on a content will predict a higher score of self-objectification. To test this hypothesis a simple linear regression was conducted to predict self-objectification based on number of likes.

Comment: In order for anyone to help you interpret the results, they would need to know what data you collected, and what question you are asking with regression.

Comment: @HarveyMotulsky thank you for your comment I have added tested hypothesis.

Comment: What is the scale of your independent and dependent variable. Looking at the intercept, it looks like you have some kind of Likert scale response? If that is the case, your DV likely violates the assumption of normality for ANOVA (Likert scales are usually non-normally distributed) and a non-parametric version would possibly be better at detecting real effects.

Answer (score 0):

The interpretation is similar to analysis with a significant outcome. Your `B` coefficient indicate how much one changes in likes (or one unit of changes likes) affect the self-objectification. I see it is a very small number, to easier interpret the result, it might be interesting use a scale of 10 of 100 likes instead?

As with significant results you should report the confidence interval, and discuss if the upper or lower limit has a relevant effect on your outcome based on you subject knowledge. The p-value is in itself less interesting, but is often reported anyway.

The standard coefficient can be given if one want to compare with other variables with other units. But is most important if you do not have the subject knowledge to understand the units of the variables.

You can get help [here](https://www.ctspedia.org/do/view/CTSpedia/InterpretationText):

I hope this helps you

Comment: That link doesn't appear to work for me fyi